# Callback vs validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I created a callback when creating a new Client object instead of using the `validates_uniqueness_of` validation method because:

- I want to find the Client that already exists
- Add the existing Client details to my base error message

My question: **is there a more elegant way of achieving this than my solution below?**

I have the following **model**:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation_on_create :prevent_duplicate_clients

  private
    def prevent_duplicate_clients
      client = self.class.find(:all, :conditions => ["first_name = ? AND middle_name = ? AND last_name = ? AND date_of_birth = ?", self.first_name, self.middle_name, self.last_name, self.date_of_birth])

      if client.size >= 1
        self.errors.add(:base, "Client exists as #{client.first.name}")
        false
      end
    end
end
```

**NB:**

- Rails v2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put validation code in the before_validation callbacks.  Change `before_validation_on_create :prevent_duplicate_clients` to `validate :prevent_duplicate_clients`

Comment: & @CaptainPete: If I move my callback to 'validate', won't this be called for create & update methods, as I only want this to occur for new records

Comment: you can pass :on => :create to the validate class macro

Comment: However, I would get rid of fetching the results from the database and use a count instead. Fetching the results isn't needed because you already know what the value of, say, fist_name is, since you are validating uniqueness.

Comment: Actually, moving this to the validate method is the solution as it will prevent users from updating an existing Client's details to match a pre-existing Client

Answer (score 2):

If you want to take the custom validator path:

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :client_uniqueness

protected

  def client_uniqueness
    duplicates = self.class.all(:conditions => {
      :first_name => first_name,
      :middle_name => middle_name,
      :last_name => last_name,
      :date_of_birth => date_of_birth
    })

    if duplicates.present?
      errors.add_to_base "Client exists as #{duplicates.map(&:name).to_sentence}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't this just a tad unnecessary? `#{duplicates.map(&:name).to_sentence}` Since if this validation is always obeyed there won't ever be multiple duplicates.

Comment: Yep. It demonstrates one of my favourite ActiveSupport helpers and Ruby shortcuts though! I figured @Coderama would replace with whatever was needed in context.

Comment: @diedthreetimes Very good point. In most cases, one would verify the data was clean according to this validation, to test that assumption before writing it in. In this case I've just assumed the data is dirty.

Comment: Actually this validation (along with validates_uniqueness_of) can be disobeyed easier than you think. Just have a user click a sbubmit button a few times in a row quickly. If two different server processes are handling the requests simultaneously then it can create a race condition where they arn't aware of eachother. This chould give you a better picture of whats happening. Check out the "Concurrency and integrity" section at the bottom of this page http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason this can't be done in a validation. Via the `validate` class method ([Doc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validate)).

If you want a cleaner model, or are using this in multiple models it can be slightly DRYer by using a custom validator.

You could then have something like this

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_uniq_with_custom_message :first_name, :middle_name, :dob #etc
end
```

Here is a good [blog](http://chrisblunt.com/2009/04/18/rails-writing-dry-custom-validators/) on the subject

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track—my question would be whether you should add an error or simply add the details to the existing client.